# In logic levels, why are the driver and receiver depicted as inverters?

Tags: logic-gates, logic-level

In Digital Design and Computer Architecture (Harris and Harris), the following schematic is given [image: figure 1.23], in discussing logic levels.

Why are the driver and receiver depicted as inverters?

Comment: The simplest use of a single transistor that improves the noise margin ---- is the inverter.

Comment: Probably because they invert the logic of thr signal. A simple common-emitter bjt config is an inverter.

Answer (score 3):

Just for convenience. This is the simplest case, and the easiest to understand at the transistor level.

Comment: I don't understand why black boxes aren't used? Isn't the logic circuit of both the driver and receiver arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, but a black box doesn't imply that we're talking about primitive logic gates so it could be **more** confusing. In any event, the narrative text that surrounds the image should provide the proper context.